# Use MinLength in Html Helpers

Tags: html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, html-helper

I have a text box in my application which I have created using `Html.TextBoxFor`. Now I want to restrict this text field to certain character whose value is dynamic and I get it from the controller. I'm able to able to restrict the Maximum length using `@maxlength`. But I can't find anything for setting the minimum value.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by using `@maxlength`? If you want to limit the number of characters, decorate you property with the `[StringLength]` validation attribute

Comment: @StephenMuecke If I decorate the property using `[StringLength]` it has to come to the controller for checking this condition and on fail redirect back to the view. I want it to be done in the front end. So that control doesn't have to come back to the controller every time. using html Maxlength property I was able to restrict the max characters, I want to do something similar for min lenth as well.

Comment: it will validate clilent-side if you include jQuery's unobtrusive validation

Comment: There is no point using the `maxlength` attribute - that client side only and you must also validate server side. Using `[StringLength]` gives you both client and server side. But if the lengths are not known, then you can can create your own validation attribute where the lengths are based on other properties

Answer (score 0):

There is no Html attribute on a textbox for Minimum Length in MVC HTML helper. You can use data annotations to enforce a maximum and minimum text length for that field.

Here is example:

```
[StringLength(250, MinimumLength = 2, ErrorMessage = "Minimum 2 & Maximum 250 character allowed")]
public virtual string ApplicationDARemarks { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar issue in ASP.NET Core 6, where using attributes on the model for StringLength generated a maxLength attribute in the html, but did not include the minLength I had included.

From my viewModel:
`[Required(ErrorMessage ="Must fill out tag name")] [StringLength(50,ErrorMessage = "Tag Name must be between 3 and 50 characters", MinimumLength = 3)] public string TagName { get; set; }`

Directly including minLength as an html attribute worked for me:

`@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.RowVm.TagName, new {@class = "form-control", required = string.Empty, @minLength = 3})`

generated Html:
`<input class="form-control" data-val="true" data-val-length="Tag Name must be between 3 and 50 characters" data-val-length-max="50" data-val-length-min="3" data-val-required="Must fill out tag name" id="RowVm_TagName" maxlength="50" minlength="3" name="RowVm.TagName" required="" type="text" value="">`

I wanted to use the Constraint Validation API for HTML 5 for form validation, and this did the trick for me.